# Why am I getting empty string on my android application?

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

This is the code that I am using as of now:

```
 try {
            JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
            //JSONObject userdata = root.getJSONObject("userdata");
            JSONArray userdata = root.optJSONArray("userdata");


            for(int i=0; i < userdata.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = userdata.getJSONObject(i);

                NAME = jsonObject.getString("name");
                EMAIL = jsonObject.getString("email");
                PASSWORD = jsonObject.getString("password");
                //data += "Node"+i+" : \n NAME= "+ NAME +" \n EMAIL= "+ EMAIL +" \n PASSWORD= "+ PASSWORD +" \n ";
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you post your Json response?

Comment: Something is wrong with your code, or your JSON. Sory, I can't use magic outside Hogwarts, so you have to post more details like the content of the `s` string, and what is empty exactly

Comment: Thanks for replying guys. This is my JSON:-> {"userdata":[]}

Comment: class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            String data="";
            int tmp;

Comment: try { URL url = new URL("http://*****/laravel5.1/blog/public/showusers");
String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;
 HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
data+= (char)tmp;
}
is.close();
 httpURLConnection.disconnect();
return data;
}

Comment: catch (MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();} catch (IOException e) e.printStackTrace();
return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
} }
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
String err=null;
JSONArray userdata= null;

Comment: This is my android code

Comment: after userdata=null then comes the json parsing part

Comment: try {
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
   //JSONObject userdata = root.getJSONObject("userdata");
  JSONArray userdata = root.optJSONArray("userdata");
  for(int i=0; i < userdata.length(); i++){
 JSONObject jsonObject = userdata.getJSONObject(i);                    NAME = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    EMAIL = jsonObject.getString("email");
                    PASSWORD = jsonObject.getString("password");
                    //data += "Node"+i+" : \n NAME= "+ NAME +" \n EMAIL= "+ EMAIL +" \n PASSWORD= "+ PASSWORD +" \n ";
                }
            }

Comment: I tried JSON array too! getting the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `JSONArray userdata = root.optJSONArray("userdata");`
Use the Method `getJSONArray` and Make sure u have passed the Correct Key value
As inspected the are no syntax error found

Comment: The issue got resolved... it was just a simple UI error! Fault was in XML code!